# application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized

Tags: python, pyside2

[image]

I ran my program and it keeps showing this error.

I'm using pyside2,and I also tried reinstall but none of them are working.

Comment: [Qt Forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/93085/qt-python-development-pyside2/3) shows same issue with conda, maybe same issue?

Comment: Possible related with [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51367446/pyside2-application-failed-to-start] In my case, Alaa Akiel's answer solute my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try to copy these files and folders beside Your EXE file:

```
   platforms\qwindows.dll
   styles\qwindowsvistastyle.dll
   Qt5Core.dll
   Qt5Gui.dll
   Qt5Widgets.dll
```

[Qt for windows deployment](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html)