# Application failed to start because no Qt platform olugin could be initialized

Tags: windows, qt, pyqt5, paraview

I have a problem with running Paraview software on my Windows 11 computer. Every time I try to open the program, it crashes and shows an error message that says "This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. Available platform plugins are: minimal, offscreen, windows."

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the program, copying the platforms folder from `...\Site-Package\pyQt5\Qt\Plugins` to `...\Site-Package\pyqt5_tools\Qt\bin` , and following some advice from this previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495620/qt-5-1-1-application-failed-to-start-because-platform-plugin-windows-is-missi), but I still can't get it to work.
Could you please let me know of any mistakes I may be making? Here is the screenshot of the error [image]

Comment: Not sure if it works for Python but have you tried using [winqtdeploy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/windows-deployment.html)? If it does not work, have you copied the other DLLs (such as the `QtCore` / `QtGui` dlls to your executable folder)?

Comment: Thanks. I haven't tried winqtdeploy but copied the DLLs to the executable folder without any luck.

Comment: I am a C++ guy so I'm afraid I cannot help more but I suggest you list **exhaustively** what DLLs you copied and where + what the command line to start your application is, with the working folder. That will give you a better chance to get an answer from someone else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62368453/application-failed-to-start-because-no-qt-platform-plugin-could-be-initialized)